# Getting API key from API on google Chatbase

Tags: chatbase

I would like to create Chatbase bots for new users/domains automatically.

For example if user has used Google-login and his authorization key is stored and analytics information like website url etc is fetched it would be nice to automatically create a bot for user.

So the question is: is there a possibility to get API-key for new bot programmically on Google Chatbase from API?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to programatically create or edit Chatbase API keys.